# Force to set multiple child at the same time

Tags: firebase

I'm serching for a solution for a backend and firebase same interesting, but I have some questions before starting to using it.

My question will be base on the exemple https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html
in the section "Validating Data".

In this exemple, They create a widget and a widget must have a color and a size. They validate this with this line: "".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['color', 'size'])","

After this line, this will happen

```
// PERMISSION_DENIED: does not have children color and size
ref.set('foo');
// PERMISSION DENIED: does not have child color
ref.set({size: 22});
// PERMISSION_DENIED: size is not a number
ref.set({ size: 'foo', color: 'red' });
// SUCCESS (assuming 'blue' appears in our colors list)
ref.set({ size: 21, color: 'blue'});
```

And after, if the client want to update a child, this will succeed

```
// If the record already exists and has a color, this will
// succeed, otherwise it will fail since newData.hasChildren(['color', 'size'])
// will fail to validate
ref.child('size').set(99);
```

My question is: can we force the client to always update the size and color at the same time. If the client try this "ref.child('size').set(99);". I want to refuse and only accept something like "ref.set({ size: 21, color: 'blue'});" even if the record already exist.

Then I want the this happen on the client:

```
ref.set({ size: 21, color: 'blue'}); //Sucess, now size and color exist
ref.child('size').set(99); //Fail, you did not update color at the same time
ref.set({ size: 22, color: 'red'}); //Success, you just change the size 
                                    //and the color. You didnt create a new
                                    //value, you change value already there
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you answered your own question:

The rule you posted:

> ".validate": newData.hasChildren(['color', 'size'])"

will only accept writing data to the node where color and size are set. Add !data.exists() to verify it doesn't already exist.

This passes:

```
ref.set({ size: 21, color: 'blue'});
```

This fails:

```
ref.set({ size: 21 });
```

The key here is the newData ensuring that the new data conforms to the rule. And then adding !data.exists() to ensure the data doesn't already exist.

There are a few other ways to enforce this as well.

Comment: Thanks, but If I understand your anwser, you add "!data.exists() to verify it doesn't already exist". Then, if the user try to change to value, it will fail because the data exist. But I want to allow the client to change the value even if the data exist.

Then if the client

ref.set({ size: 21, color: 'blue'}); //Success, value exist now

I want this "ref.child('size').set(99);" fail, but "ref.set({ size: 21, color: 'blue'});" will succeed. Does My question clear or I just don't undestand the anwser?

Comment: The !data.exists would only apply when you don't want to overwrite existing data. If you want to be able to change the data even if it exists, leave that out. The answer I provided will allow you to overwrite existing data as long as it includes size and color as children.

Comment: Then, you answser is to do "".validate": newData.hasChildren(['color', 'size'])"". But from  https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html the command "// If the record already exists and has a color, this will
// succeed, otherwise it will fail since newData.hasChildren(['color', 'size'])
// will fail to validate
ref.child('size').set(99);" will succeed. then the website is wrong or am I missing something

Comment: Remember: the validation with newData looks at both the existing data as well as the new data. If you at one time wrote color: blue to that node (before there was a rule) and then later write size: 99, it will succeed since the node is required to have both color and size. If it didn't previously have a color: blue then it will fail as that's required by the validation.  If you put a rule in place that requires both children and that either the node does not exist at all, or that both children already exist, that will enforce both children to be updated at the same time.

Comment: Thank,I will have to test it. But it's seems possible. Thanks